# Ruby Gems dependency error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I am very very very new to RoR and I'm doing this on my windows 7 environment.
Yeah I know, "why not ubuntu?"  We tried..performance was dog slow.

Anyway, I have RoR running on my machine and I created a test app aptly named, "testApp".

I run it in the browser..voila!  No biggie.  I have my basic website.

Now when I try and run it with a checked out website on my desktop, I get this

```
C:\devApp>ruby script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:in     `requirement': undefined local variable or method `version_requirements' for
#<Rails::GemDependency:0x35eae38> (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:254:in `activate'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `block in add_gem_load_paths'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from C:/srw/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

And no server is started.  I've gone through all my gems to make sure I have the right versions as per my lead developer tells me.  And we both are scratching our heads now.

Can someone help me figure out what dependency I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because your RubyGems version is out of date. Try running `gem update --system` to update it to the latest version

Comment: tried this to no avail.. but now I have alot more NOTE: alerts about gems being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your bundler, maybe of any-one of the older gem is conflicting with latest one, this type of issues arises.

```
'gem install bundler'
```

and then `'bundler install'`

If you find again error, then delete GEM.lock file, then run `bundler install`. It may resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are trying to run an application without all the required gems, I would try installing all the gems that are mentioned in the "Gemfile" (root of the app), and running the application again.

As a Windows user, I would really suggest that you try to do your rails learning and development in Ubuntu (like I do). It is much easier to install, mantain, test applications and get help.